# Use Boost::Geometry Polygon boolean/intersections with line segment properties

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, boost-geometry

Can Boost::Geometry polygon intersection operations (boolean operations of intersection, union or difference) be used while retaining custom properties that a user might assign to a line segment of that polygon?

For example, using Boost::Geometry, would the boolean operations between two polygons in the image below preserve the colours of the line segments in the original polygons in the way shown?

[Image of polygon operations with edge properties as colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7CFz.jpg)

As one can define custom point_xy objects to feed into the boolean operations algorithm, it would be possible to assign properties to a vertex of each polygon as input.  The question is: will the output retain these properties in a predictable way?

If Boost Geometry can do this, how would we go about it?

Note: there is a related question regarding linestrings here: [Find all linesegments=edges within a certain distance to a point in a graph, how to combine boost-graph with boost-geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318651/find-all-linesegments-edges-within-a-certain-distance-to-a-point-in-a-graph-how) , but as I understand it, Boost Geometry must define polygons with points, not line segments for boolean operations.

Answer (score 1):

No, retaining these properties is not yet possible in Boost.Geometry.

It was planned once, so maybe it will be there in the future. In that case you will be able to provide a kind of strategy which defines the way how to merge properties of different inputs.

But for now it is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can think of a way of adding these properties to the output polygon after the boolean operations.  Not very performant, as it would have to find which original lines each output line segment corresponds with.